# Swift and taking in more than 2 shorthand parameters

Tags: swift

Swift Language Guide shows the use of $0 and $1 as Shorthand Argument Names with this example:

```
sort([1, 5, 3, 12, 2, 5, 5]) {
    return $0 > $1
}
```

What determines that there are 2 arguments for the above and not 3?

Answer (score 4):

The definition of sort:

```
func sort<T>(inout array: [T], predicate: (T, T) -> Bool)
```

Notice that the predicate has two parameters of type T as indicated by `(T, T)`